# Prometheus dynamic port service discovery with Marathon/Mesos

Tags: java, go, prometheus, mesos, marathon

I've been unable to find an answer to this after days of Googling. I have a service running in Marathon/Mesos. I have a Prometheus cluster scraping metrics. My Marathon metrics port config looks like this:

```
{
  "containerPort": 8081,
  "hostPort": 0,
  "servicePort": 31301,
  "protocol": "tcp",
  "labels": {
    "metrics": "/metrics"
  }
}
```

Prometheus, configured with just a boilerplate marathon-sd config, successfully finds this target, but it then listens for metrics on: `__address__ = [NodeIP]:31301`; so it's listening on the host's IP with the service port, rather than the dynamically assigned host port, while the service port only matters for Marathon-LB.

I know that Marathon defines the environment variable `$PORT0` in the container to be the host port, however I can't figure out how to access this from the Prometheus SD config, nor how to access other fields dynamically configured by Marathon like `Endpoints`. Does anyone have any suggestions? I can't/don't want to assign a static `hostPort` because I have more containers than there are physical nodes in the cluster, as is sort of the point with container orchestration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known bug in Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4855): it uses the `servicePort` Marathon app definition property instead of the `hostPort` one. It is [fixed in the v2.6.0](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.6.0).